# how to delete the inserted row by the delete button

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to delete the entered task by the delete button which is created by the end of each task. I am posting my full code here
It's a simple to-do list by using bootstrap CDN .

I want to delete the row which contains user enter task,serial number,time and date.

```js
var task = document.getElementById("enter");
var bttn = document.getElementById("button2");
var rowIdVar = document.getElementById("test");
var rowIdVar1 = document.getElementById("id1");
bttn.addEventListener("click", add);
var x = 0;

function add() {
  var val1 = task.value;
  if (!val1) {
    alert("Please Enter A Task");
  } else {
    sno();
    name();
    tdate();
    time();
    cButton();
    var new1 = document.createElement("l");
    rowIdVar1.appendChild(new1);
  }
}

function sno() {
  if (x == x) {
    x = x + 1;
    var list1 = document.createElement("l");
    list1.innerHTML = x;
    rowIdVar.appendChild(list1).setAttribute("class", "col-md-2");
  }
}

function name() {
  var val = task.value;
  var list2 = document.createElement("l");
  list2.innerHTML = val;
  rowIdVar.appendChild(list2).setAttribute("class", "col-md-4");
  task.value = "";
}

function tdate() {
  var d = new Date();
  var date = d.getDate();
  var month = d.getMonth();
  var year = d.getFullYear();
  var result = (date + "/" + month + "/" + year);
  var lm = document.createElement("l");
  lm.innerHTML = result;
  rowIdVar.appendChild(lm).setAttribute("class", "col-md-2");
}

function time() {
  var t = new Date();
  var hour = t.getHours();
  var minutes = t.getMinutes();
  var seconds = t.getSeconds();
  var result1 = (hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
  var lm1 = document.createElement("l");
  lm1.innerHTML = result1;
  rowIdVar.appendChild(lm1).setAttribute("class", "col-md-2");
}

function cButton() {
  var btn = document.createElement("input");
  btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  btn.setAttribute("value", "delete");
  btn.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-danger");
  rowIdVar.appendChild(btn).setAttribute("class", "col-md-2");
  btn.addEventListener("click", deleteElements);
}

function deleteElements() {
  rowIdVar1.parentNode.removeChild(rowIdVar);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 h">
      <center>
        <h1>TO DO LIST...</h1>
      </center><br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 bg">
        <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Enter task" id="enter">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm=2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="button2"><center>ADD</center></button>
      </div>
    </div><br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="id1">
      <div class="col-md-2 b">
        <h1>S.no</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 b">
        <h1>Enter Task</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 b">
        <h1>Date</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 b">
        <h1>Time</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="test">
    <div class="col-md-2"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var task = document.getElementById("enter");
var bttn = document.getElementById("button2");
var rowIdVar = document.getElementById("test");
var rowIdVar1 = document.getElementById("id1");
bttn.addEventListener("click", add);
var x = 0;
function add() {
  var val1 = task.value;
  
  if (!val1) {
    alert("Please Enter A Task");
  } else {
    sno();
    name();
    tdate();
    time();
    cButton();
    var new1 = document.createElement("l");
    rowIdVar1.appendChild(new1);
  }
}

function sno() {
  if (x == x) {
    x = x + 1;
    var list1 = document.createElement("li");
    list1.innerHTML = x;
    rowIdVar.appendChild(list1).setAttribute("class", "col-md-2");
  }
}

function name() {
  var val = task.value;
  var list2 = document.createElement("li");
  list2.innerHTML = val;
  rowIdVar.appendChild(list2).setAttribute("class", "col-md-4");
  task.value = "";
}

function tdate() {
  var d = new Date();
  var date = d.getDate();
  var month = d.getMonth();
  var year = d.getFullYear();
  var result = (date + "/" + month + "/" + year);
  var lm = document.createElement("li");
  lm.innerHTML = result;
  rowIdVar.appendChild(lm).setAttribute("class", "col-md-2");
}

function time() {
  var t = new Date();
  var hour = t.getHours();
  var minutes = t.getMinutes();
  var seconds = t.getSeconds();
  var result1 = (hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
  var lm1 = document.createElement("li");
  lm1.innerHTML = result1;
  rowIdVar.appendChild(lm1).setAttribute("class", "col-md-2");
}

function cButton() {
  var btn = document.createElement("input");
  btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  btn.setAttribute("value", "delete");
  btn.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-danger");
  rowIdVar.appendChild(btn).setAttribute("class", "col-md-2");
  btn.addEventListener("click", deleteElements);
}

function deleteElements() {

 rowIdVar.parentNode.removeChild(rowIdVar);
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body id="body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 h">
      <center>
        <h1>TO DO LIST...</h1>
      </center><br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 bg">
        <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Enter task" id="enter">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm=2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="button2"><center>ADD</center></button>
      </div>
    </div><br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="id1">
      <div class="col-md-2 b">
        <h1>S.no</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 b">
        <h1>Enter Task</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 b">
        <h1>Date</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 b">
        <h1>Time</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="test">
    <div class="col-md-2"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: it works fine but after adding multiple task it removes all of them.
suppose i entered 3 task and each one have three different delete button if i click any of the button rather deleting that particular row it deletes all of the entered task

Comment: Give all the tasks row dynamic id and onclick get their id using `this`. Then delete the specific row using the id

Comment: what if i add a function to create rows and provide id to them inside the onclick event on add button .. 
and on the delete button i just delete the row by their id
will it work ?